# How to texture/model a huge terrain for open-world game?

Tags: modeling, texturing

Considering a city terrain, it is pretty various: somewhere there is an asphalt road with a good bordures, somewhere road and bordures broken so it smoothly turns to the curb, into the pedestrian part, etc... Somewhere there is a grass, a river or a lake

How to properly deal with that? Make one single surface, subdivide, create separate materials for separate faces, or make one huge texture?
Or to create terrain by parts as separate meshes?

I want it for a game. How do games with open world like GTA do this? I am asking exactly about terrain (floor\ground) not buildings, trees or another stuff

[image]

Comment: @moonboots, can You explain in details?

Comment: Why not a big picture and you just paint with a stencil brush? Not sure how they organize the ground texture in games though, I guess it's with some tiles, no?

Comment: @moonboots I think it should be *at least* 8k texture